# Extension only works when I tapped Clear button in Modifications

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have this extension( [link](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?rout%20...%20_id=672006) ) that enables the admin to write a short description for each product, in order to be different than the actual description. This can be shown before clicking on a product, after you get your search results etc etc.

After copying all the files into my ftp, it seems that the extension only works when I click the `Clear` button in `Extensions -> Modifications`, but it disables ALL the rest extensions.

If I press refresh all those OTHER extensions are fully working, but this one does not(an extra textfield should be shown on Admin->Products->edit product.

Any idea what is here that I can do? something to do with the cache?

Tried
- a clean install of the module removing all xml
- tried it on a local version of opencart (still the same results)
- replaced all files of this extension with a clean one

I could really use some help here.
Cheers in advance

*Using opencart 2.0.3.1 version and latest vqmod*

Comment: May be your old extension and this new extension are trying to change the same file. Which may cause problem.

Comment: Have you looked into Modification Log? It should show you all related information.